# Two states on UITableViewCell and AutoLayout breaking constraints

Tags: ios, autolayout, uitableview

I'm trying to do a two different states for `UITableViewCell` but when I change the size of the cell, this change break many constraints `AutoLayout`.
The two states are:

[image]

[image]

- Yellow is the cell
- Gray is custom `UIView`
- Orange is another `UIView` inside A
- Red are two `UILabel` inside B

Initial state is unfolded but when I reduce the `height` of the row to change to folded state, many constraints (mainly `UIView B` and `UILabels`) break `AutoLayout`

Steps:

1. Clic on cell, and change size of the cell
2. Hide `UIView` B
3. Reload `UITableView`

Is there any way or approach no avoid breaking constraints? Maybe two different cell designs?

Thanks!

Comment: you will need to include the constraints you have on those objects for us to help you

Comment: You can't just change the size of a cell. The UITableView needs to reloadData and then you can change it, for example.

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog I updated images with constraints

Comment: @mattsson Yes, I did

Comment: You can use a stack view to handle constraints and hide /show view b

Comment: you could use 2 different cell designs, or toggle presence of a stack view. but don't just change the height of the cell, you should let the table view use automatic dimensions and auto layout to achieve the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution in you case would be using two cells with different identifiers - one containing view A, another one containing views A,B. Then you could `.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: %CELL_A_OR_CELL_B_IDENTIFIER%, for: indexPath)` depending on your needs.

Less suitable solution is to use stack view or adjust your constraints. In both cases the only way to avoid conflicts and prevent incorrect layout is to properly set constraint priorities. I would try to set constraint in circle priority to something less 1000 (like 990)

[image]